# Comparing strings in multiple R data frames to retrieve the first characters that are in agreement

Tags: r, string

I have the following data frames in R.

```
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("ACTG","ACT","GTAC","GTC","GACT")))
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("AC","ATC","GTCA","GC","GAC")))
```

I am trying to determine what the longest possible string that is consistent between the two Nucs columns.
So far, I have tried this:

```
x1 <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Nucs),"")
x2 <- strsplit(as.character(df2$Nucs),"")
x <- Map(intersect, x1, x2)
sapply( x, paste0, collapse="")
```

This gives me the following:

```
[1] "AC"   "ACT"  "GTAC" "GC"   "GAC"
```

which is not quite what I want because in the case of Site 3 I have GTAC and GTCA so I only want the first two characters that are consistent in the string, i.e. GT.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I also find a solution that you can try:

```
CompareVectors  <- function(x, y){
  comp_length <- min(length(y), length(x))
  x <- x[1 : comp_length]
  y <- y[1 : comp_length]
  compare <- x == y
  id <- which(compare == F)[1]
  if(!is.na(id)){
    x <- x[which(compare[1: (id - 1)])]
  } 
  return(paste(x, collapse = ""))
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
  sapply(1 : length(x1), function(i) CompareVectors(x1[[i]], x2[[i]]))

[1] "AC"  "A"   "GT"  "G"   "GAC"
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's my not very efficient solution:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("ACTG","ACT","GTAC","GTC","GACT")))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("AC","ATC","GTCA","GC","GAC")))
x1 <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Nucs),"")
x2 <- strsplit(as.character(df2$Nucs),"")
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  a = ""
  for(j in 1:min(length(x1[[i]]),length(x2[[i]]))){
    a=    paste(a,x1[[i]][j] == x2[[i]][j],sep=",")
    }
  print(head(x1[[i]],sum(as.logical(strsplit(a,",")[[1]][-1]))))
  }
```

Output:

```
[1] "A" "C"
[1] "A"
[1] "G" "T"
[1] "G"
[1] "G" "A" "C"
```

Would you like me to comment the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, although a bit lengthy:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {
                                 s1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$Nucs[x]), split = ''))
                                 s2 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df2$Nucs[x]), split = ''))
                                 n <- min(length(s1), length(s2))
                                 i <- 1 
                                 while(i <= n) {
                                  if (s1[i] != s2[i]) {
                                    break
                                  }  
                                  i <- i + 1
                                 }
                                 if (i > 0) 
                                   paste(s1[1:(i-1)], collapse ='')
                                 else
                                   ''
                        })
# [1] "AC"  "A"   "GT"  "G"   "GAC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. It may not be covering all possible cases but that's probably easy to extend.

```
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("ACTG","ACT","GTAC","GTC","GACT")))
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(Site=c(1,2,3,4,5),Nucs=c("AC","ATC","GTCA","GC","GAC")))

mapply(x = as.list(df1$Nucs), y = as.list(df2$Nucs), FUN = function(x, y) {
  x <- as.character(x); y <- as.character(y) # doesn't work with factors

  # To keep everything in one easy to debug chunk, just switch in case
  # x is shorter than y.
  if (!(nchar(x) >= nchar(y))) {
    xp <- y
    yp <- x
  } else {
    xp <- x
    yp <- y
  }

  # create elements to work on and vector for storage
  to.glue <- strsplit(xp, "")[[1]]
  out <- rep(NA, times = length(to.glue)) # used as output

  # If one string is shorter than the other, extract one element
  # at a time and see if there's a match in y. If yes, then pro-
  # ceed to the second element, concatenate it with the first
  # one and see if this pattern is present anywhere in y...
  for (i in 1:length(to.glue)) {
    glued <- paste(to.glue[1:i], collapse = "")
    fm <- pmatch(x = glued, table = yp)
    if (is.na(fm)) {
      return(out[i-1])
    } else {
      out[i] <- glued
    }
  }
})

[1] "AC"  "A"   "GT"  "G"   "GAC"
```